# Does anyone know how they did this UI keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Anyone knows how they did this UI keyboard:
http://img87.imageshack.us/i/tastiera.png/ ?

Thanks,
Fabrizio

Answer (score 3):

The only way to tell if it is a custom UIView is to see if it lacks the features of the normal keyboard.  I simply cannot believe anyone completely duplicated the keyboard feature for feature just to change the tint of it.

If it is not a custom UIView, then that leaves only one other option: private API calls.  Is this app on the App Store?  Private APIs are a no-no of course so I doubt this is the standard keyboard *and* available on the App Store.

UPDATE:

Of course, now we have Extensions with iOS 8 and you can create your own custom keyboards.  It doesn't help make creating a keyboard any easier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, seems to be a custom UIView with Custom UIButtons.

Comment: I don't know, looks like photoshopped to me.

Comment: Yeah, they probably "photoshopped" all the characters and special keys and put them as an image on the button. looks dirty.